# My code doesn't work - ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

Sorry for mybad English:

After correcting of my code, it doesn't want to show more.
Is there someone who can check my code ?

```
try 
{
    if ((Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) < 3) || ((Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) > 15)))
    {
        Response.Write("it works?"); //small test of my code.
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
catch (Exception)
{

}
```

and please explain what you've done?

Comment: What "doesn't work" about the code?

Comment: It would probably be more apparent if the potential exception wasn't getting swallowed.

Comment: wat error does it give?

Comment: Remove the catch block temporarily and run it. But calling Convert.ToInt32() on a textbox text property without checking if it's a number first isn't going to work too well.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `try-catch` for integer parsing. You can use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like:

```
int value;
if (int.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out value) && (value < 3 || value > 15))
{
    //valid values
    Response.Write("it works?"); 
}
else
{
    //invalid values
}
```

Comment: @user3319482, what is the value in your `TextBox`, also what exactly you need to check *(e.g. Range??)*

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox> this is my textbox